# What’s a word for not knowing what to do or say?

Tags: word-choice

For a response from hatchet the book (3 paragraphs)

Comment: Single word requests need a sample sentence into which you wish the word to fit, so that it can be clearly seen what context and what part of speech is relevant. Please see Help and Tour. I have supplied a sample sentence in my own answer, below, but please feel free to choose your own for your question.

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.

Answer (score 2):

> **[nonplussed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonplus)** [nänˈpləst] adjective - (of a person) surprised and confused so much that they are unsure how to react.

Not that the word has taken on an incorrect meaning recently to mean "unaffected," but etymologically it is quite clear: to be so stimulated that you process *no more* (*non - plus*)

Answer (score 1):

He was **confounded** by what he saw.

> Discomfited, abashed, put to shame or mental confusion; confused, disordered

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38964?rskey=ifHBR7&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Trump successes **confound** foes

[Journal Publishing - 28 Sep, 2018](https://www.abqjournal.com/1226644/trump-successes-confound-foes.html)

> Travel Agent ‘Comeback’ Continues to **Confound** the Public

[Market Report - Oct 3, 2018](https://www.travelmarketreport.com/articles/Travel-Agent-Comeback-Continues-to-Confound-the-Public)